# Meaning and Underlying idea of a definition or a theorem

Tags: definition

What does it mean by 'explain the meaning and underlying idea of a definition or a theorem'?

For example, if we are asked to explain the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, how should we explain its meaning and idea?

I can only think of saying: The theorem tells us that every single variable polynomial can be expressed into a product of linear factors.

What else should I say? I think I am just stating the theorem, nothing more. I am very confused right now.

Comment: To what does "it" refer in your opening sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question I want to cite [this answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/913/5097) to a question on matheducators.stackexchange.com:

> "Math educators mostly agree that for a given object or property, people usually have a picture in mind (maybe many pictures). We call this their *concept image*. The students also might have a *concept definition* in mind, hopefully the definition you gave to them." – [Anschewski](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/199/anschewski)

The formal definition or theorem stated in the textbook is the *concept definition*. You are asked to give also the *concept image* of the theorem. The following questions might help you:

- What do you have in mind, when you think about the theorem / definition?
- Why is this theorem important?
- For what is the definition / theorem used for?
- What is the motivation behind the definition / theorem?
- How can you illustrate the definition / theorem?

The answer by Anschewski also links to the book [Ideas from Mathematics Education](http://www.mathstore.ac.uk/headocs/AlcockBook_Book.pdf) where you might find some help.